# Accessing the values of msg in node-red

Tags: javascript, node-red

I have a node-red node that reads values as follows :

[image]

The msg I'm getting is :

[image]

So I want to work with the values inside the `msg.payload. array`. 
for the I wrote the following :

[image]

well the result is undefined, so I don't know what I'm missing here ?

[image]

any idea how may I solve this ?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you have connected the function node to a different output on the modbus node than the debug node so you are not getting the input you expect.

I can't find the exact node to check what is actually sent on the second output, but I'll guess that it is actually uses for errors or state changes.

The fix is to move the wire that links to the function node to the first output on the modbus node, then it will get the same message as the debug node.